# Fullcalendar.io - multiMonthYear to display up to +1 year

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

Wondering if anyone could shine some light on Fullcalendar v6.1.5

I'm trying to display the Fullcalendar to allow toggling up to +1 year from current year. Tried various methods even by trying to disable the fc-nextYear-button but, they don't even disable.

Also tried getFullYear and setFullYear though, unsuccessful.

Comment: try : maxDate: new Date().getFullYear() + 1

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, still able to scroll infinite years

Comment: Please post minimal reproducible problem and thing that you have tried.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code you are trying so we can try to understand the issue in detail.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of endless googling, I have the solution! In order to achieve this, I needed validRange and visibleRange with custom date specifications. With my case being unique of start = CURRENT YEAR and end = YEAR AFTER, Here's what I did.

```
var startOfYear = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  

var startOfNextYear = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() + 2, 0, 1).toISOString().slice(0, 10);

initialView: 'multiMonthYear',

    visibleRange: function() {
      return {
        start: startOfYear,
        end: startOfNextYear,
      };
    },
    validRange: function() {
      return {
        start: startOfYear,
        end: startOfNextYear,
      };
    },
```

Hopefully that helps someone. Spent HOURS looking for this.